# Change weight based on custom option

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options, shipping-methods

We have two shipping methods: package and postal. Postal is the cheapest.
We have shipping rules based on weight.
One of our products is large sheets of paper, because this cannot be send as postal we gave this product a high weight.
This works fine, when a large sheet of paper is ordered the package shipping method is selected.

Now we've added a custom option to the product, saying 'cut before sending'.
When the customer selects it, we will cut the large sheet of paper in 4 and send it as postal.
But how can we change the weight of the product when the 'please cut' option is selected? The package shipping method is still selected, but the postal method should be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul,Magento have magic logic to change the `weight of cart item`.When magento is added a product in cart it fire an event `sales_quote_item_set_product` and it send two  params
one is `Quote item(Quote Object)`  and  another is Current Carted product object(`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`)

See at Class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`  event

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_set_product', array(
    'product' => $product,
    'quote_item' => $this
));
```

I suggest to the trigger an [event/observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) on this occasion and you can change weight of quote items using `setter` function `setWeight()` and another thing is that magento is save `quote item weight` at `sales_flat_quote_item` Table at database.

### Code of Observer:

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento53367_Model_Observer
{
    public function setweightCustomOption(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $Event = $observer->getEvent();

        //Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_set_product', array('product' => $product,'quote_item' => $this));
        $product=$Event->getProduct();
        $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
        $quote_item->setWeight(900);
    }
}
```